# Fortran interop with C function pointer wrong results

Tags: c, fortran, gfortran, powerpc, fortran-iso-c-binding

I have a C program that calls a Fortran subroutine in a static lib. This subroutine takes as argument a function pointer to a callback implemented in C. A minimal example looks like this:

Fortran code:

```
subroutine fortran_function(input, c_function) bind(c)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    real(c_float), value, intent(IN) :: input
    type(c_funptr), intent(IN), value :: c_function
    abstract interface
        subroutine callback(a, b) bind(c)
            USE iso_c_binding, only: c_float, c_int
            integer(c_int), intent(IN), value :: a
            real(c_float), intent(IN), value :: b
        end subroutine callback
    end interface
    procedure(callback), pointer :: c_proc
    
    call c_f_procpointer(c_function, c_proc)
    
    call c_proc(1_c_int, input)
    if (input > 1.0) call c_proc(2_c_int, input)
end subroutine fortran_function
```

C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (*c_function)(int, float);
void fortran_function(float, c_function);

void callback(int a, float b)
{
    printf("a=%d, b=%.1f\n", a, b);
}

int main()
{
    fortran_function(0.0, &callback);
    fortran_function(5.0, &callback);
}
```

If I compile this (Intel and MSVS on Windows) everything works fine and I get the expected output:

```
a=1, b=0.0
a=1, b=5.0
a=2, b=5.0
```

However, I ultimatley want to target a powerpc (using gfortran and gcc-variant crosscompiler). The program compiles there without warnings (-Wall) but produces the output:

```
a=1, b=0.0
a=2, b=0.0
a=1, b=5.0
a=2, b=5.0
```

This is very strange because for the first call the flow should never enter the if-body. Apparently it does so anyway, but even prints the correct value for the input.

Compiled on Ubuntu with:

```
powerpc-linux-gnu-gfortran test.f90 -c -Wall -pedantic
ar cr test.lib test.o
```

What I already checked:

- Replacing `if (input > 1.0)` with `if (input > 1.0_c_float)` doesn't solve the problem
- Using pass-by-reference instead by-value on the function pointer crashes instantly (on Windows it runs fine)
- Turning of optimization (on both the C and Fortran part) doesn't solve the problem
- All types are 4 byte `sizeof(real)=sizeof(real(c_float))=sizeof(integer)=sizeof(integer(c_int))` (same in C)

Does anyone have an idea what could possibly cause this problem?

Comment: Have you stepped through this using a debugger? If yes, what can you report?

Comment: @francescalus I can't unfortunatly because I have no debugger for the μC... Actually this is an attempt to "debug" the Fortran part with only printf available in the C part of the program...

Comment: Without a debugger (although if you're developing for ppc I'd imagine getting a debugger on the target would be a good investment in time), can you print the value of `input` in the Fortran subroutine to see what value it is there? Also, what versions of compilers, endianness of host and target, how compiled, etc.?

Comment: @francescalus The problem is that to get the console output I have to use a custom printf function (with a quite complicated implementation) that is only available in C. Therefore I wanted to pass a function pointer so I can print in the first place. I can't print directly from Fortran (I would have to replicate the printf). Host is little, target big endian.

Comment: My guess would be that the Fortran library is interpreting the float bit pattern incorrectly (such as wrong endianness).  About the only other way I can think to test that is by a `call c_proc(1_c_int, 5._c_float)`.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger... the Fortran code is short and straightfoward - have you inspected the compiler's output at an assembly level?